# A list of books for discovering mathematics using computer software

Tags: reference-request, big-list, math-software

I'm searching for books that allow one to discover/experiment with mathematics by using computer environments such as Mathematica/Magma/Magma/Pari-GP, etc.

Until now, I discovered these:

- [Discovering Mathematics: A Problem-Solving Approach to Mathematical
  Analysis with MATHEMATICA® and
  Maple(TM)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0857290541)
- [Discovering Mathematics with Magma: Reducing the Abstract to the Concrete (Algorithms and Computation in Mathematics)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540376321)
- [Mathematica® in Action: Problem Solving Through Visualization and Computation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387753664)

Comment: I think that this question would work better if you make it a CW.

Comment: Still dunno how to do this.

Comment: See also [Books on Experimental Mathematics](http://www.experimentalmath.info/books/).

Comment: @lhf Great link!

Comment: I do not feel this is an appropriate question for a StackExchange site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations/131432#131432

Comment: @JoshuaDrake This isn't Stack Overflow.  Questions like this are asked all the time here and I think they are good.

Comment: @Graphth obviously local rules take precedence. I am curious how you'd address the points made in my meta post. What happens in 3 years when several new versions of MATHEMATICA and Maple have been released, or when there are brand new interactive environments for R available, will not the dated references below be nearly useless to someone else stumbling onto this question?  You may have gotten a lot out of Title X, but that may have depended a lot on context, no?  How is someone not familiar with the topic going to do with that book? etc.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake *How is someone not familiar with the topic going to do with that book?* Perhaps asking it on stack exchange?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to learn about **graph theory**, there is a book called [Algorithmic Graph Theory](http://code.google.com/p/graphbook/) that uses Sage: "Theory and algorithms are illustrated using the Sage open source mathematics software."  This book is free.  There's also a link on that site to [Explorations in Algebraic Graph Theory with Sage](http://buzzard.pugetsound.edu/sage-practice/) by Beezer and Godsil, which is also free.

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in **number theory**, William Stein wrote a book called [Algebraic Number Theory, a Computational Approach](http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/ant/), which uses Sage quite a bit throughout to illustrate points.  And he also wrote [Modular Forms, A Computational Approach](http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/modform/modform/) which uses Sage quite a bit throughout.  These are both free.  The second one you can download [here](http://modular.math.washington.edu/books/modform/stein-modform.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

Here's a couple of links. I am not sure that those fulfill your request, though.

[This](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~harold.boas/courses/math696/Maple.html) is a course in Maple by H. Boas. It is primarily aimed at learning the basics of Maple. Nevertheless, the chapter "Slicing bread with Maple" is intended as a computer-aided lecture on higher-dimensional geometry and I find it both amusing and interesting.

['Experiments with MATLAB' by Cleve Moler](http://www.mathworks.it/moler/exm/index.html). The title is pretty much self-explanatory: it is a book in which MATLAB is employed to work out some college-level mathematical facts. This book is a spinoff of the classic [Numerical Computing with MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.it/moler/index_ncm.html) by the same author.

Comment: It's helpful. Thanks. =)

Comment: @Gustavo: You are welcome. I am glad that helped! You have started a nice question, I'll fav it.

Answer (score 3):

As these questions appear to be acceptable around these parts, I'll add:

- [SciPy and NumPy](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920020219.do)
- A second for [Mathematica Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596521004.do?green=2A6F2E9C-0D5B-50CD-BA17-50E014FC4D52&intcmp=af-mybuy-9780596521004.IP)
- [R in a Nutshell](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596801717.do) and [R Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596809164.do?green=2A6F2E9C-0D5B-50CD-BA17-50E014FC4D52&intcmp=af-mybuy-9780596809164.IP)
- [Exploring Everyday Things with R and Ruby](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022626.do?green=2A6F2E9C-0D5B-50CD-BA17-50E014FC4D52&intcmp=af-mybuy-0636920022626.IP) which covers "learning how to assemble, process, simulate, and analyze the available data"
- [Excel Scientific and Engineering Cookbook](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596008796.do)

Answer (score 2):

[Computations in algebraic geometry with Macaulay2](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/Macaulay2/Book/)

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to learn **statistics**, the book [SAS for Data Analysis: Intermediate Statistical Methods](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387773711) is a book that is about learning statistics while you are using SAS.  The first few sentences of the book description on Amazon read:

```
This book is an integrated treatment of applied statistical methods, presented
at an intermediate level, and the SAS programming language. It serves as an
advanced introduction to SAS as well as how to use SAS for the analysis of
data arising from many different experimental and observational studies.
While there are many introductory texts on SAS programming, statistical
methods texts that solely make use of SAS as the software of choice for the
analysis of data are rare.
```

Answer (score 1):

This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but [The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~jve/HR/) by Kees Doets and Jan van Eijck is a wonderful introduction to discrete mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in **cryptography**, [Introduction to Cryptography with Open-Source Software](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/143982570X) uses Sage.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to learn Classical Mechanics, you should check [SICM](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicm/). The idea of the authors is to benefit from the clarity and the flexibility of the Scheme programming language, in order to offer a hands-on approach. It is especially useful for beginners, since the use of a programming language helps avoiding many confusing ambiguities of the mathematical language employed in traditional books on Mechanics.

Answer (score 0):

[The Student's Introduction to MATHEMATICA ®: A Handbook for Precalculus, Calculus, and Linear Algebra [Paperback]](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521717892)

Answer (score 0):

[Mathematica Cookbook](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596520999)

(Dummy text for the 30 characters limit)