# What are good introductory books on the various math software packages?

Tags: reference-request, math-software

I feel like I've finally gotten a good grip on mathcad, and would now like to start going through the other popular software packages (Mathematica, Maple, and Matlab). Could anybody recommend general entry-level texts on each? I  have seen a number of things on Maple and Mathcad, but they seem focused on specific topics (computational math, ee, etc.) Is there something like an o'reilly "missing manual" for any of this stuff?

Comment: See also: [A list of books for discovering mathematics using computer software](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/198471/80812).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Matlab, I'd refer you to [The Elements of MATLAB Style](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521732581) by Richard K. Johnson. This book is reviewed by Loren Shure on [her MathWorks blog](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2011/02/10/book-review-the-elements-of-matlab-style/). Beyond the [many tutorials available](http://www.mathworks.com/academia/student_center/tutorials/launchpad.html) might also look at this post on [Good MATLAB Coding Practices](http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/01/14/good-matlab-coding-practices/) that links to several free PDF guides for users that have already learned the basics.

You can browse a huge list of Matlab-related books by subject area, publication date, and language [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/books/), including the general ["Using Matlab"](http://www.mathworks.com/support/books/index_by_categorytitle.html?category=17) section.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab help is fantastic. Seriously,I've met three or four tools/products that had really good built-in help/documentation and Matlab was one of them. Basic programming and basic tasks are covered very well. Many toolboxes also have the same high-class documentation. I never felt that I need book when I was doing Matlab.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. To be honest I feel like I learned mathcad the way I did because the book was organized a certain way. Thats largely why I raised the question. But I will take a look all the same.

Answer (score 0):

For Matlab I prefer "Introduction to Matlab" by Ross Spencer and "Applied mathematical problems with Matlab" by D. Xue and Y. Chen (but the last book is with problems that need to be solved).